# Can I restrict file names to be valid on Windows?

Tags: windows, sync, filename

I sync certain folders to Windows and to One Drive, and if I have a file with invalid characters like `\/:*?@<>|` or I have two files in the same folder with the name `Cube.png` and `cube.png` it raises errors.

Is there a way to restrict my system (or that folder) to be Windows names only?

Comment: Very good question! I think not, but let the experts in this field give their opinions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about special characters but there is a FUSE filesystem overlay that can mount one directory as case insensitive to another [ciopfs - Case Insensitive On Purpose File System](http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/ciopfs/).

```
sudo apt-get install ciopfs
mkdir ~/.ciopfs-source
mkdir ~/sync-files
ciopfs ~/.ciopfs-source ~/sync-files
```

You should read the documentation from the link above and test thourly before using this to sync any important data.

> To avoid any conflicts you should not manipulate the data directory
>   directly, any change should be done over the mount point. **Any
>   filenames in the data directory which aren't all lower case are
>   ignored.**